# mb_split returning strange characters for RTL

Tags: php

I'm trying to split Arabic words into array but it always return some strange characters.
[image]
Here's the code:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
function fatehah(){
    $surah = "
بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ ١ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ٢ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ ٣مَـٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ ٤إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ ٥ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ ٦صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ   ٧
    ";
    $words = mb_split("\s",$surah);
    //shuffle($words);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++){
        $word[] = $words[$i][0];
    }
    return $word;
}
$selwords = fatehah();
var_dump($selwords);
?>
```

Comment: And that's correct if you just display `$surah`...? Or is it the same problem...?

Comment: What exactly you try to do? Return first letter of each word?

Comment: If you do want the first letter, use `mb_substr($words[$i], 0, 1)` instead of `$words[$i][0]`, which will take the multibyte character of the letters into account.

Comment: @Justinas splitting words in the sentence into array with each array containing only 1 word.

Comment: In that case simply return the result of `mb_split("\s",$surah)` without the `for ()` loop.

Comment: Why not capture each word? Unrelated to question but `count()` shouldn't be used as argument for `for`, use `foreach` when working with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only first letter of each word, use [`mb_substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead:

```php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
function fatehah(){
    $surah = "
بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ ١ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ٢ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ ٣مَـٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ ٤إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ ٥ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ ٦صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ   ٧
    ";
    $words = mb_split("\s",$surah);
    //shuffle($words);
    
    return array_map(
        fn ($word) => mb_substr($word, 0, 1),
        $words,
    );
}
$selwords = fatehah();
var_dump($selwords);
```

[Example](https://onlinephp.io?s=lVPLSsNQEF0byD8MwUUCFXUn1MfOL9CdUKJNTKFNw02iiAjio5Yu0jR_4LMiiBWxol9y52-cuTetUtyYQuCee-acM5Pp6kYURKbR2q01wsQToduseeFeu94I921re2tzYcVyqqbhp-Fe0miH4LuJF7iB7RybBtAzH6fCDWANLNOQj5jLNyzwEnPAV7ygX4YDvCqP8pWP8lkxMjzFEXZmr3Ls6fJrJVAQlBFQyBfsAwH5L00uYk8cQEn-LGUvVBFrdTADvPm3--2Uw5bnDPUI6P5qjhKRs7Ig4E7eq2rWGVIBuZI1BSooYV-n7xLwJ4tmJp8UW0cm7j1ZXKm2c0UZas939lRxR_KDy1XflKk_EcGzsgu6fGD-LJu9R9PZyFsCOuXoLrUEqAMze6RNk-YLkF8aIL38xzcjuJBj7GOXP8Xfpdw5g5MuxirEjZrtoAwCgEO9Ula1XK3DtqjHtFq0nHHUbCS2tRNbFb1xTklaXIyD1Pebnq3pE1y_hZekIgRXCPeo1nIjW8P8-CHoEgfW1pVFuhsnQmMVWKrAslP5oWt1AubY4cQ05mOvOQk4_VPQ1YEravW0FdlTglP9Bg%2C%2C&v=8.2.1)

---

If you want to have each word in its own array:

```php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
function fatehah(){
    $surah = "
بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ ١ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ٢ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ ٣مَـٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ ٤إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ ٥ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ ٦صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ   ٧
    ";
    $words = mb_split("\s",$surah);
    //shuffle($words);
    
    return array_map(
        fn ($word) => [$word],
        $words,
    );
}
$selwords = fatehah();
var_dump($selwords);
```

[Example](https://onlinephp.io?s=lVPLSsNQEF0byD9cQhcJVLoVanXnF-hKJUSbmEKbhjwUEUF81NJFmuYPbK0VQWwRK_old_7GmXuTWoobUyi9554558x0srntu76qtI7MhhfZgWc1Tds7btcb3omu7e3urG9oRlVVnNg7jhptjzlWZLuWqxsXqsLwKYVxYLmsxjRV4c-Q8nfI4A5SBjO4xU8CA7jPj3xGR_4qGAlcwRQ6q1cp9GT5gxDIEEoQyPgb9BkC6ZImFZEnDFhO_splb0URaXUgYTD8t_towSHLG4J6CHSXmsNE6CwsEHjkY1FNOhMsQFe0xkAZJuzL9F0E_mThzPiLYMvIyB2jxb1oOxWUifT8IE8Rd8o_qVz0jZn6hQhc513g5RPxV9nkPV3Mho8Q6OSju5MSTByI2UNtnDRdMP4tAdRLf30ThDM-hz506a_4u5Q6J7DoYi5CDMVsB3kQxmAiV0qr5qt11g7qIa4WLmfoNxuRrh2EWllunJGTKpXQjR2naeuSXuDyO7CjOPCYFQTWudmyfF3C9DgekyUGq22xffHzsPx7L-UQWCPJS1UphXazSLR4C_Dq1ArMetzy9QXBqP4A&v=8.2.1)

---

If you want just array of word, simply do `return mb_split("\s", $surah)`